# new Object or new Object()

Tags: javascript, object, standards

```
var Obj = new Object;
```

or

```
var Obj = new Object();
```

When I tried both in the console both codes worked. Which is the correct format. Where can I find these JS standards.

Comment: Use neither, create a simple object using the literal `var obj = {};`

Comment: @PaulS. I would like to know where I can find standard uses like these.

Comment: "standard uses"? You can an annotated version of the standard with which javascript is specified here: http://es5.github.io/

Comment: Your best bet would be MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new As you can see, the brackets are optional. Of course, if you want to pass arguments to your constructor, you'll need to use brackets.

Comment: The brackets are optional if you're not giving arguments, whether you use them depends on the convention you follow, e.g. Crockford would tell you to always use them (as can be seen by typing into http://jslint.com ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brackets `()` are used to pass parameters to constructor, e.g.:

```
new Stuff("string", 3);
```

You can still create an object without using `()` if you do not need to pass parameters. (For example `Object` does not require any parameters)

Answer (score 2):

```
var Obj = new Object;         //empty object
```

or

```
var Obj = new Object();      //empty object
```

or

```
var Obj = {//---- 
          };                 //empty object
```

---

all do the same stuffs, because in all of them you are not passing any arguments,If you do not have arguments to pass, then parentheses are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
var obj = {
    /* what your object does */
}
```

Some sources, for example [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), suggest this as the standard approach.

Comment: w3schools is not related to the w3, WHATWG or any other body like that

Comment: @PaulS. where did he say it's related?

Comment: @Bart I mean it as in, you can't rely on w3schools as a primary source as it's not a standards body and it's full of inaccuracies

Comment: @PaulS. This is what I have used when I started and I still refer to it as a good source. I have not found a grave inaccuracy yet, while I do admit that they keep things rather simplistic.

Comment: @PaulS. By that logic the only website you can rely on is www.ecma-international.org and some very dry specifications that nobody wants to read. Yet everyone keeps linking to MDN too. For some reason that's ok. Also, w3fools.com is incredibly outdated and most of the crap there has been corrected. I wonder why nobody lists all the corrections that have been made to MDN on MDNfools.com

Comment: @Bart He also called it "W3C". On the topic of MDN, first off it's a wiki so can be fixed immediately if you see an error and secondly Mozilla are behind the Gecko engine. However, I'll agree that w3schools may have done a lot of work and that many people use it when starting out. Lastly, if you find the [ecma-international copy](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) of the ES5 spec difficult to read there is a nice annotated version [**here** es5.github.io](http://es5.github.io/) which is pleasently coloured and fully hyperlinked, too

Comment: @PaulS: I agree. The way it was formulated could make you believe that this was an official W3C source which is not the case. I changed the sentence to be a bit more neutral. (After all, SO is collaborative)